# How can I reset the scale of a canvas' context?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a variable, context, which is the 2d context of my canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Calling `context.scale(x,y)` multiple times scales the context depending on what the previous scales did. For example, `context.scale(2,2); context.scale(2,2)` is equivalent to `context.scale(4,4)`. How can I reset the context's scale?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`scale` will multiply the current transform matrix by a scale matrix, so indeed, these scale factors multiply. You can use the state stack to save and restore the current transform:

```
context.save();
context.scale(2, 2);
... // anything drawn here is twice as big
context.restore();
```

Alternatively, you can reset the transform by loading the identity matrix directly:

```
context.scale(2, 2);
...
context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks - which one would you recommend, or is there no difference?

Comment: Depends on your needs. You can actually use the stack to your advantage, for example, if you want to draw part of the scaled-up imagery with yet another transform. The main drawback of using the stack is that you have to make sure to match up your `save` and `restore` calls, or you'll end up with stack overflows/underflows. Also, the stack saves all the state, not just transformations. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations for more.

Comment: @ANON, In addition to having to manage the save/restore stack, you will also get a modest performance hit due to the quantity of properties it must save & restore. If you're just scaling, `setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` is better.

Comment: For the performance : do not worry, browsers are smart enough to save/restore only what changed. Advantage of save/restore is that it allows you to perform transforms that will affect all 'child' draws. Think drawing a car for instance, by drawing its parts (wheels, ... ,... ) when you later scale/translate/... the car, everything goes well. (vs having to change all parts draw function.)

Comment: +1 for `context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);`. This is a good general purpose reset, and a useful way to clean up a drawing function which includes multiple transforms.

Answer (score 6):

The following method is clearer, however it is experimental.  That is to say everything except IE and Edge support it.

`context.resetTransform();`

As of 2019 the sensible option is still:

`ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/resetTransform#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Could you also provide a relevant quote from the source listed at the end? Links tend to rot away/break with time.